# PHP date() function

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm having an auto created timestamp on update from the database that looks like this: 
y/m/d h:i:s..

And when I want to echo it it's like: Y/m/d h:i:s, and what I would like it to be is: d/m/Y H:i:s..

But if I use this:

```
$date = $row['created_timestamp'];  
 $date_added = date('d/m/Y', H:i:s);
```

It'll print the date right, but the time is the current time. How do I change this to be the stored time from my database?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT()` in MySQL to pull it out in any format you want and save yourself the extra parseing/formatting step in PHP: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$date_added = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Should do the trick.